# Fixing wrong delimiter in string

Tags: python, regex

Given the incorrect string:

```
s="rate implies depreciation. Th  e straight lines show eff ective linear time trends in the nominal (dashed "
```

I want to output the correct string like:

```
s="rate implies depreciation. The straight lines show effective linear time trends in the nominal (dashed"
```

If I try to remove all the delimiter using :

```
re.sub("\\s*","",s)
```

it will give me: 
"rateimpliesdepreciation.Thestraightlinesshoweffectivelineartimetrendsinthenominal(dashed", which is not what I want

Comment: You are removing all the whitespace - I don't see how you could achieve what you want, as there is no way to tell the difference between what you want to remove (e.g. the space in the middle of `eff ective`) and spaces between the words.

Comment: I agree with @Ollie .. I don't see any way to distinguish a unique pattern about the spaces you're after vs others...could be wrong

Comment: Aside from what the other comments mention, you may try this: Find out what the exact characters are which appear as whitespace. If you are in luck, it may turn out that in the between the words ```The``` and ```effective```, it is not ```space``` but ```tab``` or some other whitespace character. You may then call ```re.sub()``` just for those particular characters rather than for ```\s```.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to check the word spelling, with pyspellchecker for example

(pip install pyspellchecker)

```
from spellchecker import SpellChecker
spell = SpellChecker()

s="rate implies depreciation. Th  e straight lines show eff ective linear time trends in the nominal (dashed "
splitted_s = s.split(' ')
splitted_s = list(filter(None, splitted_s)) #remove empty element in between two consecutive space
```

And then either check if a word doesn't exist but previous_word+word does:

```
    valid_s = [splitted_s[0]]
    for i in range(1,len(splitted_s)):
      word = splitted_s[i]
      previous_word = splitted_s[i-1]
      valid_s.append(word)
      if spell.unknown([word]) and len(word)>0:
        if not spell.unknown([(previous_word+word).lower()]):
          valid_s.pop()
          valid_s.pop()
          valid_s.append(previous_word+word)

    print(' '.join(valid_s))

 >>>rate implies depreciation. Th e straight lines show effective linear time trends in the nominal (dashed
```

But here because e exist as a word in dictionary it doesn't concatenate th and e

So you can also compare word frequency and concatenate previous_word and word if previous_word+word is (much) more frequent in dictionary than word:

```
    valid_s = [splitted_s[0]]
    for i in range(1,len(splitted_s)):
      word = splitted_s[i]
      previous_word = splitted_s[i-1]
      valid_s.append(splitted_s[i])
      if spell.word_probability(word.lower())<spell.word_probability((previous_word+word).lower()):
        valid_s.pop()
        valid_s.pop()
        valid_s.append(previous_word+word)


    print(' '.join(valid_s))

 >>>rate implies depreciation. The straight lines show effective linear time trends in the nominal (dashed
```